# javascript- redirect page in the same directory of my website

Tags: javascript

I have to redirect my page to another page,but in the same directory.
For example: www.test.com/demo/test.php 
I have to redirect to :

```
www.test.com/demo/check.php
```

And because that i have a lot of environment like dev QA production i have to keep the beginning of the path and just redirect to another page.

If i write:

```
function redirect (){
   document.location = '/check.php'; //redirect me to www.test.com/check.php
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `document.location = 'check.php'`

Comment: And if you leave out the slash at the start of the url? `document.location = 'check.php';`

Comment: I might not get your question right but I would just remove the leading slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but if if all you're asking is how to redirect to a file in the same directory, simply remove the `/` from your code.

```
function redirect (){
   document.location = 'check.php'; 
}
```